# How to blur a Network Image in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, blur

does anyone know how to blur an Image.Network in flutter?

```
Image.network(

                  user.profileImageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text(
                    user.name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
double _sigmaX = 0.0; // from 0-10
double _sigmaY = 0.0; // from 0-10
double _opacity = 0.1; // from 0-1.0

Container(
  width: 350,
  height: 300,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      image: Image.network(user.profileImageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                )
    ),
  ),
  child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: _sigmaX, sigmaY: _sigmaY),
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(_opacity),
    ),
  ),
);
```